# Problem using jid:make/2 in ejabberd-18.09

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-hooks

I am using ejabberd-18.09.
I have this code

```
MucCreateReply = mod_muc:create_room(HostName,Roomname,jid:decode(Name),NickName,default),

RoomJid = jid:make(Roomname, HostName),
```

where

```
HostName = <<"conference.abc.com">>,
Roomname = <<"1/A16/-LWKYb1Zl7YheHuQ80Fi">>
```

but this line `RoomJid = jid:make(Roomname, HostName),` results in RoomJid being 'error' even when mod_muc:create_room/5 runs successfully and i can see the room being created alright.

I am having trouble understanding it.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone going through the same problem here is the solution -  removing `/` from the room name did the trick.